# Nothing happens when pressing Enter while searching using Android Search widget

Tags: android, search

I am trying to implement the search widget in android but unsuccessful. It lets me type the query text in the seacrh textbox but nothing happens when I press Enter. I followed the tutorial very closely http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html.  But I can't fix the problem. I've been trying everything for 6 hours now. Please help!

Here is my Android manifest file:

```
            <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

            <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">


            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value="com.example.pt_labguide.SearchableActivity" />


           <activity
           android:name="com.example.pt_labguide.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>


          </activity>

          <activity android:name=".BasicMetabolicPanelActivity" 
              android:label="@string/basic_metab_panel" >
          <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.pt_labguide.BasicMetabolicPanelActivity"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
          </activity>

         <activity android:name=".ArterialBloodGasActivity" 
              android:label="@string/arterial_blood_gases" >
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.pt_labguide.ArterialBloodGasActivity" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity android:name=".DisplayLabValueActivity">    
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.pt_labguide.DisplayLabValueActivity" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity">

       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.pt_labguide.SearchableActivity" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" /> 
       </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
       </activity>     

       </application>

      </manifest>

      ****Here is the Searchable activity:****
      package com.example.pt_labguide;


    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;   
    import android.util.Log;


     import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;  
     import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
     import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
     import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;

    public class SearchableActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
    handleIntent(getIntent());

    }


    @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
    Log.d("SearchResultsActivity", "onNewIntent called");
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
        Log.d("SearchResultsActivity", query);
    }
   }

   private void doMySearch(String query){

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.pt_labguide.DisplayLabValueActivity");

     intent.putExtra("labValue", query);
     startActivity(intent);
  }
  }


  **Here is the Main activity:**
  package com.example.pt_labguide;

  import android.app.Fragment;
  import android.app.SearchManager;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
  import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;

  import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
  import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
  import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
  import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

  import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.content.Intent;



 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{



     @Override 
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        // Notice that setContentView() is not used, because we use the root 
        // android.R.id.content as the container for each fragment 

        // setup action bar for tabs 
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); 


        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab() 
            .setText(R.string.list) 
           .setTabListener(new TabListener<ListFragment>( 
                  this, "list", ListFragment.class)); 
       actionBar.addTab(tab); 

       tab = actionBar.newTab() 
               .setText(R.string.categories) 
               .setTabListener(new TabListener<CategoryFragment>( 
                      this, "category", CategoryFragment.class)); 
           actionBar.addTab(tab); 

       tab = actionBar.newTab() 
                 .setText(R.string.favorites) 
                 .setTabListener(new TabListener<FavoriteFragment>( 
                      this, "favorite", FavoriteFragment.class)); 
           actionBar.addTab(tab); 

       tab = actionBar.newTab() 
                  .setText(R.string.about) 
                  .setTabListener(new TabListener<AboutFragment>( 
                        this, "about", AboutFragment.class)); 
            actionBar.addTab(tab); 

     }

    static class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements                 ActionBar.TabListener { 
    private android.support.v4.app.Fragment mFragment; 
    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity; 
    private final String mTag; 
    private final Class<T> mClass; 

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created. 
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment 
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment 
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment 
      */ 
    public TabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) { 
        mActivity = activity; 
        mTag = tag; 
        mClass = clz; 
    } 

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */ 

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { 
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized 
        if (mFragment == null) { 
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity 
            mFragment = SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName()); 
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag); 
        } else { 
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it 
            ft.attach(mFragment); 
        } 
     } 

     public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { 
        if (mFragment != null) { 
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached 
            ft.detach(mFragment); 
        } 
     } 

     public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) { 
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing. 
     } 
      }//end inner class


     @Override
     public boolean onSearchRequested() {

        return super.onSearchRequested();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();

      inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

     // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
      SearchManager searchManager =
             (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
      SearchView searchView =
              (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(
              searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
      searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
       return true; 


     } 

     public void display_BMP (View view) {
       startActivity(new                Intent("com.example.pt_labguide.BasicMetabolicPanelActivity"));
   }

   public void display_ABG (View view) {
       startActivity(new Intent("com.example.pt_labguide.ArterialBloodGasActivity"));
   }

   public void display_LabValue (View view) {

         String name = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
         Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.pt_labguide.DisplayLabValueActivity");

         intent.putExtra("labValue", name);
         startActivity(intent);
       }
}//end class TabDemo 


  **Here is the menu/search.xml:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.example.pt_labguide="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"

      android:title="@string/search_hint"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_lens"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />
   </menu>


      **Here is the raw/xml/searchable.xml:**

             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
             </searchable>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ENter key?

Comment: The enter key or return key in the keyboard